# MySQL Trigger not firing AFTER INSERT

Tags: mysql

I have created a new trigger in my MySQL database to update a cell value after an insert. The cell that I want to update (gp_per) as default is set to a null value.

Here is the trigger:

```
SET @gp_per = ((@retail_price - (@retail_price * 0.23)) - @cost_price) / (@retail_price * 0.23)
```

It created fine and I got no syntax errors but when I try to insert a new row, the gp_per cell is down as NULL rather than updating with the correct value. I haven't really used triggers before so I'm not 100% sure what I am doing wrong.

Below is the trigger:

[image]

And the structure of the table:

[image]

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: What you did creates session variables, it doesn't touch any column values. How about you read about triggers first before asking for help? Their syntax is trivial, if you know basic SQL queries, you can handle triggers as well.

Answer (score 0):

As MySQL documentation on [creating triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html) says:

> Within the trigger body, you can refer to columns in the subject table (the table associated with the trigger) by using the aliases OLD and NEW. OLD.col_name refers to a column of an existing row before it is updated or deleted. NEW.col_name refers to the column of a new row to be inserted or an existing row after it is updated.

Still MySQL documentation on [trigger examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) says:

> In a BEFORE trigger, you can also change its value with SET NEW.col_name = value if you have the UPDATE privilege for it. This means you can use a trigger to modify the values to be inserted into a new row or used to update a row. (Such a SET statement has no effect in an AFTER trigger because the row change will have already occurred.)

The above means that you need to use

```
SET NEW.gp_per=((NEW.retail_price - (NEW.retail_price * 0.23)) - NEW.cost_price) / (NEW.retail_price * 0.23)
```

expression **and** you need to change your trigger to be a **before** insert trigger. You can also consider using a generated column instead of a trigger, if your MySQL version supports it.